# Hibernate <generator class="" > When is it best to use what?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am relatively new with Hibernate. I used Persistence and Toplink prior to this but didn't help too much when learning Hib. When I define my entity classes, specifically the id attributes,I find myself not knowing which values to use. Obviously theres different situations that call for different values. What do some of these values mean and which ones are used most often? Like say I have an oracle db that supports sequencing..what choice would i use then? Or when it mentions using the "identity" value in non-clustered environments, what does that mean? clustered databases or clustered application servers? Alot of the language hibernate uses seems pretty generalized? or im just a noob :-p thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose **native** if you want something simple that works and is portable between different database engines.

[Hibernate documentation 5.1.4.1. Generator](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator)